# How to resolve a domain name to a single IP address?

Tags: .net, tcp, domain-name

I was surprised to learn that a single domain name can have many IP addresses. For example, here are my results for `Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.com")`:

```
{System.Net.IPAddress[6]}
    [0]: {74.125.127.147}
    [1]: {74.125.127.99}
    [2]: {74.125.127.103}
    [3]: {74.125.127.104}
    [4]: {74.125.127.105}
    [5]: {74.125.127.106}
```

(YMMV; the addresses seem to change periodically)

Where do these different addresses come from, and how should one choose an IP address to connect to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP addresses come from the DNS server associated with the queried domain name, www.google.com in your example. This would be the same process a web browser follows to get the server IP addresses to connect to.

As for which IP address to connect to I'd imagine they're all redundant and you should probably just connect to the first one, however this is just speculation and I don't really know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a reason to specifically bind to the IP, you should use DNS to resolve at the moment you make the connection.

As for the "where do they come from", thats answered by any number of infrastructure decisions.  This is the power of DNS, in that load balancing, caching, delivery, etc systems can dynamically serve up a domain (example.com) from any number of sources without you (the client) having to worry about that implementation.

The multiple DNS can be multiple servers, different datacenters, cache networks, etc ... depending on any  number of factors.

Comment: "you should use DNS to resolve" - isn't that precisely what Dns.GetHostAddresses does? Problem is, it resolves not one address, but many.

Comment: Sure, but what are you trying to do?  Most clients (web, soap, etc) are going to ask you for the hostname vs the IP address.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is understand how domain names are, or should be, resolved. I am interested in the "why". I noticed that if I use TcpClient to connect, though, that there is a constructor overload that takes a string and allows a domain name or IP address, so for that method of connection it is not necessary to resolve the domain manually.

Comment: Well thats what I'm getting at, whenever possible (and really it's usually possible) the DNS should be resolved at runtime.  So long as you are doing that (and it seems like you are), then you are free to use any of the IPs provided, so long as you are resolving them pretty much on the fly every time (dns caching fits into this too, but out of scope).  What I was suggesting is that almost all of the .NET methods will have a constructor or method that leverages a hostname vs an IP address, so I would advice using those vs. binding yourself.  But if not, you can trust any of those IPs.

Comment: Okay, so just doing GetHostAddresses(name)[0], as Dave suggested, would be an acceptable practice. But if applications normally just take the first address, why does DNS provide multiple addresses? I wonder if a web browser does something more complex, like try connecting to each IP in turn with a certain timeout, until one of them works...

Comment: Sure, the DNS implementation is going to be very different based on the client app ... which is why my answers are somewhat vague.  At that level it really depends what you are doing? (a local ip vs a remoate one, for example)

Answer (score 1):

There are most likely using some sort of RoundRobin.

You can only rely on a domain name, unless the domain is under your control.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things:

1. Use System.Net.IPAddress[0] right
   off the bat.
2. You can ping all 6 and
       see which one has the best response
       time, cache that value and try to
       use it later.