# Parsing an IPv6 loopback address to a Uri

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-web-api

I've written a client/server application which I'm testing on my local machine.

The server reads the IP Address of the client as `::1` which is an IPv6 loopback address.

However, I need to re-establish an HttpClient connection to this client later, by providing a Uri's BaseAddress:

```
  var originalAddress = "::1";
  var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(originalAddress) };
```

This results in the exception `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

How can I get the Uri to accept this address?

Comment: do a google search on how to resolve `IPv6 to a URI` here is a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277060/is-there-a-standard-net-decoder-for-ipv4-and-ipv6-addresses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in other posts, the solution is to wrap brackets around the IPv6 address in accordance with [RFC 2732](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt):

```
var uri = new Uri("http://[::1]:8080");
```